# Stylesheets & Wolfram Cloud

Tags: stylesheet, wolfram-cloud

Can one use a custom stylesheet in Wolfram Cloud?  I didn't see such an option but maybe there's a non-obvious way.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

They work, but you need to a) write stylesheet notebook expression or b) edit in desktop > upload and then set `StyleDefinitions` programmatically.

Additionally `SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], StyleDefinitions -> ...]` may not refresh styles automatically but if you reopen the notebook it should be ok.

Try it on a saved cloud notebook and reopen it:

```
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[],
  StyleDefinitions->Notebook[{
    Cell[StyleData[StyleDefinitions->"Default.nb"]],
    Cell[StyleData["Notebook"],Background->Red],
    Cell[StyleData["Input"],CellFrame->True]
  }]
]
```

[image]