# What is the proper way of setting ` CellContext -> CellGroup` in the Wolfram Cloud Notebook?

Tags: notebooks, wolfram-cloud, contexts

I want a [different evaluation context for different sections of my Notebook](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/211221/how-to-keep-symbol-bindings-local-to-a-notebook-section).[Mike Honeychurch suggested to me](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/211229/68791) than changing the `CellContext` to `CellGroup` would create a different context for each section of a document. [According to the documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CellContext.html#26736), this seems to the right thing to do.

However, I'm unable to use that properly in the Wolfram Cloud Notebook. Here is a screenshot of my current session. Cells were evaluated by "Evaluate All" in the menu:

[image]

As you can see despite my use of `SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], CellContext -> CellGroup]` at different places, the `$Context` is always set to `` Global` ``.

What is the proper way of setting The Notebook evaluation option `CellContext -> CellGroup` in the Wolfram Cloud Notebook?

---

<sub>Eventually related to [Stylesheets & Wolfram Cloud](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/193164/stylesheets-wolfram-cloud), since, to quote Mickael E2 in a comment below *"In the documentation pages, this seems to be done through the stylesheet"*</sub>

Comment: In the documentation pages, this seems to be done through the stylesheet. They set the cell option `CellContext -> CellGroup` on both the `"Input"` and `"Output"` styles.  Examine `FileNameJoin[{$InstallationDirectory, "SystemFiles", "FrontEnd", 
  "StyleSheets", "Wolfram", "Reference.nb"}]`.

Comment: Yes, I remember having read something like that. My first attempts in using stylesheets from the Wolfram Cloud Notebook weren't that successful. But I will review that.

Comment: Outch! Examining the stylesheet with `ReadString[FileNameJoin[{$InstallationDirectory, "SystemFiles", "FrontEnd", "StyleSheets", "Wolfram", "Reference.nb"}]]` is pretty harsh on the browser :/ Do you know if there is a way to download that file from the Cloud?

Comment: Sorry, I don't use the cloud version much and am unfamiliar many such things.  I tried adding private `StyleDefinitions` to a cloud notebook.  I took them from a desktop notebook, in which `CellContext -> CellGroup` works properly.  However, on the cloud, the `StyleDefinitions` have no effect.  This might be a limitation of the WolframCloud. Maybe someone else will come along who has better knowledge than me.

Comment: Here is the `StyleDefinitions` from my desktop notebook: `StyleDefinitions -> 
 Notebook[{Cell[StyleData[StyleDefinitions -> "Default.nb"]], 
   Cell[StyleData["Input"], CellContext -> CellGroup, 
    MenuSortingValue -> 10000], 
   Cell[StyleData["Output"], CellContext -> CellGroup, 
    MenuSortingValue -> 10000]}, WindowSize -> {808, 905}, 
  WindowMargins -> {{20, Automatic}, {Automatic, 44}}, 
  FrontEndVersion -> "12.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (April 8, 2019)",
   StyleDefinitions -> "PrivateStylesheetFormatting.nb"]` -- but it didn't work on the cloud, as I said.

Comment: Thanks  Michael for the extra pieces of information. I will try to do something with that on my side.

Comment: You do not need to do this in a stylesheet. If you evaluate in a notebook you will see that it works. That is does not work on the cloud is something I cannot explain. Maybe a WRI tech can comment

Comment: My guess is that CellContext is not supported on WPC yet. The UI is converging to what we know from the destkop MMA but many FrontEnd related features are in production.

Comment: Yes, CellContext is not implemented in its entirety in the cloud yet, but it's on our list.

Comment: To download that stylesheet file from the cloud, you'd have to turn it into a proper cloud object (in your cloud directory) first, e.g. using `CopyFile[FileNameJoin[{$InstallationDirectory, "SystemFiles", "FrontEnd", "StyleSheets", "Wolfram", "Reference.nb"}], CloudObject["Reference.nb"]]`. Then you can download it using the in-browser cloud file explorer, or by executing e.g. `CopyFile[CloudObject["Reference.nb"], "Reference.nb"]` in desktop Mathematica.

Comment: One again, thanks @jan for the tip. I'm looking forward to seeing full CellContext and improved stylesheet support in the cloud (btw, are you looking for beta testers? ;)

Answer (score 4):

*A CW answer for clarity*

As of `$CloudVersion` 1.53.0.1 the `CellContext` is not supported in cloud notebooks.

> Yes, CellContext is not implemented in its entirety in the cloud yet, but it's on our list.
>
> – Jan Pöschko